# Sending Mail through scala

Tags: scala

How do I send mail in Scala? I tried this code but I am getting error an error:

> not found: object mail import mail._ ^

```
import mail._

object demoformail {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {        
    send a new mail(
      from = "rupesh.kumar@.com" -> "Rupesh kumar",
      to = "xxxxxxx@.com",
      subject = "Our 5-year plan",
      message = "Here is the presentation with the stuff we're going to for the next five years."    
    )    
  }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: not found: object mail
import mail._
       ^

Comment: And why should a package `mail` be there? From what dependency is it supposed to come?

Comment: this is first time i am coding the mail programe, i thought it is  a package required for  mail, kindly correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I believe you were trying to use the approach described in this gist: https://gist.github.com/mariussoutier/3436111 - in this case you should also include the object that's listed there alongside the code you've written to send the email. Note that that object depends on apache commons mail library - if you don't know what dependencies are, start with https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Getting-Started.html and include the dependency `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.5"`